# upgrading an alias to main domain on plesk onyx

Tags: plesk-onyx

On Plesk onyx 17.8.11 I have a domain.info and an alias domain.org.
I would set domain.org as main domain and domain.info as alias without affecting the wordpress working with domain.org.
Would be enough changing the main domain name in the hosting setting panel?
Should I first delete the alias domain.org?
thx

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a backup of domain.info: **Domains > domain.info > Backup Manage**.
2. Remove or rename alias domain.org.
3. Rename domain domain.info to domain.org.